# PHP doesn't execute query after long processing

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have a weird problem with a query that is not being executed under certain circumstances. I'm pretty sure that it's not a problem with they query itself, since I inserted a very simple query right before it, that can't be wrong but isn't executed as well.

Here's a short explanation of what this script does: The script is being executed by a cronjob every minute. It checks a list of uploaded PDF-files and splits them into separate files, if they haven't already been split, followed by a JPG-preview generation.

It works perfectly fine for average PDF-files. However uploading a large PDF-file (e.g. 30MB, 28 Pages), will make the script stop at some point for no reason (see inline comments). I have error_logged the PDF-splitting process ($pdf->process) and it works perfectly fine.

A friend suspected that this weird bug may be caused by insufficient memoryspace on the server or a reached maximum of connections to the database, but we both don't have much of a clue with those kind of things. Maybe one of you has?

```
ignore_user_abort(0);
set_time_limit(0);
error_reporting(-1);

if($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] == '127.0.0.1')
    include_once("../config.php");
else
    include_once("/home/httpd/docs/myproject/inc/config.php");

include_once(ROOT."inc/db.class.php");
include_once(ROOT."inc/functions.php");
include_once(ROOT."inc/generate_previews.class.php");

$db = DB::getInstance();
$select_file_name_query = "SELECT * FROM z_tmp_preview_files WHERE id > '0' AND status = '0' AND file_name != ''";
$result = $db->query($select_file_name_query);


while($job_preview = $db->fetchNextObject($result)){

    $job_id = $job_preview->rel_job_id;
    $file = $job_preview->file_name;

    $set_inprocess_file_name_query = "UPDATE z_tmp_preview_files SET status = '1' WHERE id = '".$job_preview->id."'";
    $set_inprocess_file_name_result = $db->execute($set_inprocess_file_name_query);

    $file_info = explode('.',$file );
    $file_name = $file_info[0];
    $jpg_file = str_replace(".pdf", ".jpg", $file);

    // =======================================================================================
    // PDF-file is split into separate pages and JPG-previews are generated with the McPdf Class
    // This works just fine, even with very large files, but may take some minutes.
    // =======================================================================================
    $pdf = new McPdf($job_id);
    $pdf->process();

    $files_burst = LoadFiles("".ROOT."intern/jobs/".$job_id."/burst/");
    $page_count = sizeof($files_burst);

    error_log("\nTEST:",3,ERROR_DIR);
    $sql = "SELECT annotation_type FROM annotations";
    $value = $db->queryUniqueValue($sql);

    // =======================================================================================
    // This is where the PHP-script just stops. Non of the following error_logs are shown,
    // nor will the UPDATE-query be executed. The previous SELECT-query probably hasn't been executed as well.
    // =======================================================================================
    error_log($value,3,ERROR_DIR);

    $remove_file_name_query = "UPDATE z_tmp_preview_files SET status = '2' WHERE id = '".$job_preview->id."'";
    error_log("\n\ncheck query:",3,ERROR_DIR);
    error_log(" ".$remove_file_name_query,3,ERROR_DIR);
    $remove_file_name = $db->execute($remove_file_name_query);

    error_log("\npossible error:".$remove_file_name."\n",3,ERROR_DIR);
}
```

The db.class works just fine, I use it everywhere in my project, but if you're wondering what queryUniqueValue does, here's the code:

```
function queryUniqueValue($query, $debug = -1){
    $query = "$query LIMIT 1";

    $this->nbQueries++;
    $result = mysql_query($query) or $this->debugAndDie($query);
    $line = mysql_fetch_row($result);

    $this->debug($debug, $query, $result);

    return $line[0];
}
```

Edit: Here's another guess: Maybe this is some kind of mysql timeout? The problem only occurs, when the McPdf class takes a very long time to process. As far as I can tell, after executing $pdf-process() the first mysql-query will abort the execution of the PHP-script.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're hitting PHPs "maximum script execution time" ? I believe it is set to 30secs by default. Try increasing the maximum execution time at the beginning of your script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time',2*60); // will set it to 2 minutes
```

HTH

Comment: I tried that and set it to 1 hour, but sadly it didn't work :/

Comment: Hmm, could be a database timeout then. After how many minutes does the timeout occur? And is that always the same?
Check out http://gauravasthana.blogspot.nl/2011/02/exploring-timeout-variables-in-mysql.html
it lists a few timeout parameters in MySQL, they might get you back on track.